# Can't access WebDriverJS wait 'until' in Protractor and CoffeeScript

Tags: selenium, coffeescript, webdriver, protractor

I need to wait for a modal to close so I am waiting for the absence of an element.  I'm trying to do something like this:

```
browser.driver.wait until.stalenessOf(By.css '.modal-header')
```

Unfortunately Coffeescript has reserved `until`.  So I tried using:

```
browser.driver.wait browser.driver.until.stalenessOf(By.css '.modal-header')
```

but it is undefined (`until` that is).  `browser.driver` exists but it doesn't contain `until`.

How can I access the until object?  Also, is there another way to wait until an element is no longer on the page?

Comment: Good question!....they alias "by" as "By" ( also a reserved word in CoffeeScript), but they don't alias "until" as "Until"?  Is there another way to access the "until" function?

Comment: Brennan! hahaha, ran into this issue as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [isPresent()](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent) function instead:

```
browser.wait ->
  not element(By.css '.modal-header').isPresent()
,
  5000
```

**NOTE:** `isPresent()` will not return false until it has finished implicitly waiting for the element, so if you have set the `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait` property very high you may want to temporarily decrease its value.